# C# wrapper to Cairo library

Tags: c#, wrapper, cairo

Does anybody have a C# wrapper for Cairo library? I need it to use to render PDF files previews on my program (in Windows and Mac under Mono)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple answer: [Mono:Cairo](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono.Cairo)

Comment: I can't use/import it directly from Visual Studio 2008 without Mono.

Comment: http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/win32-installers/modules/mono-cairo-lib/source/lib/2.0/ has a precompiled version

Comment: Foxfiree- thanks for link. Unfortunatelly I received the exception
Unable to load DLL 'libcairo-2.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) on the following code: 
            var surface = new Cairo.PdfSurface(@"testdoc.pdf", 200, 200);


Mono.Cairo.dll and libcairo-2.dll were placed into the same output folder (Debug\Bin if it's matter)

I downloaded libcairo-2.dll here:
http://inkscape.modevia.com/win32libs/cairo-1.8.0-mingw.tar.gz